# java: SwingWorker and with multiple listeners

Tags: java, arrays, swing, model-view-controller, swingworker

I'm learning to build gui applications. My current private project is working, the program is doing everything I want. But the implementation looks pretty bad and is not maintainable or extensible anymore. It is not really following MVC or other design pattern in the main parts. So I've started to rework it and would appreciate some advise.

The goal of the program:
It is a monitoring tool getting the data from an external source all the time as long as the application is running. The data is displayed (some labels, text areas, an OSM map) and updated permanently. Depending on the data a button to start the recording of the data (into a file) is enabled or not. When the recording is stopped by the user (same button) some post actions are executed.

Due to lack of knowledge I have implemented two separate SwingWorkers, one to display the current data and one for the recording, started when the button is pressed (is reading the date too!). This is my main pain point. Just one data-retrieving SwingWorker must be sufficent.

So I have started to rework it. I have a gui view class. Once the gui is initialized the SwingWorker (as a gui member variable) is executed and updates the view elements. Fine. Works. But is this a nice approach? The SwingWorker is the central object. From my feeling it should not belong to the view. Other objects should also observe and use its progress. Whenever new data came in gui elements or others should get notified. So I could add several observers to the SwingWorker and call notify(myData) within the doInBackground() method.

My second, bigger issue is concerning the start-stop button to record my data. What kind of implementation approach would you suggest? My idea was to implement a PropertyChangeListener to get the button clicked action. But how can this handle/record the data from the SwingWorker and interrupt on demand? It must get notified permanently too. Or is there some other, better pattern to pulling the data on demand? Is there a nice example with a single SwingWorker and multiple independent listeners/observers?

Thanks in advance,
Niels

Comment: You'd want to post some of what you have done so that we can have a better idea of what you have done already, so we could have an idea of what you have done, and what needs improving :)

Comment: The SwingWorker should be feeding a model, which should provide update notifications to interested parties, this means that both the ui and your recorder and listen in to changes. Alternatively, you could have a proxy model which actually did the recording and slide it in and out as required...but that's up to you...

Comment: Conceptually, the SwingWorker belongs to the UI, really, that's kind of the point, it's doing work on behalf of the UI. The problem you have is the data needs to be shared between between the UI and another thread (responsible for recording the data). What you could do, is have a Thread, which reads the data a either or both, fills a model some kind, this would then provide notification of changes.  You would then have two listeners, on for the ui , which synchronized the updates back to the EDT and the other which recorded the data from the context of a different thread, when recoding